# Cannot write a function to retrieve all words in a trie

Tags: python, data-structures, trie

I have a following Trie implementation:

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.is_fullpath = False


class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, word):
        curr = self.root
        for char in word:
            curr = curr.nodes[char]
        curr.is_fullpath = True
```

I'm trying to write a method to retrieve a list of all words in my trie.

```
t = Trie()
t.insert('a')
t.insert('ab')
print(t.paths())  # ---> ['a', 'ab']
```

My current implementation looks like this:

```py
def paths(self, node=None):
    if node is None:
        node = self.root
    result = []
    for k, v in node.nodes.items():
        if not node.is_fullpath:
            for el in self.paths(v):
                result.append(str(k) + el)
        else:
            result.append('')
    return result
```

But it does not seem to return full list of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the issues in your code:

- It doesn't look further when `is_fullpath` is True. But you should *also* look deeper (for longer words) in that case.
- It should not check `node.is_fullpath` but `v.is_fullpath`.
- `result.append('')` is not correct. It should be `result.append(str(k))`

So your `for` loop body could look like this:

```py
if v.is_fullpath:
    result.append(str(k))
for el in self.paths(v):
    result.append(str(k) + el)
```

I would however do it like this:

Define this recursive generator method on your `TrieNode` class:

```py
def paths(self, prefix=""):
    if self.is_fullpath:
        yield prefix
    for chr, node in self.nodes.items():
        yield from node.paths(prefix + chr)
```

Note how this passes the collected characters on the path to the recursive call. If at any time the `is_fullpath` boolean is True, we yield that path. Always we continue the search recursively via child nodes.

The method on the `Trie` class is then quite simple:

```py
def paths(self):
    return list(self.root.paths())
```